# Craft Commerce — Billing / Shipping Address validation / required Fields

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, form, validation

As default Craft has only `First Name` and `Last Name` as required. Is it possible to set more as this two fields as required fields? And is it also possible to set custom Fields as required too?

Answer (score 3):

It will be possible in the next release (commerce 2-beta.5):

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/342

Answer (score 3):

Address validation is, in Commerce v1 at least, generally handled via a plugin.

(I'll assume you already have a business logic plugin on the go, but if not head over to https://pluginfactory.io and use that to generate your plugin skeleton).

Then, you basically need to add a listener to `onBeforeSaveAddress` and do your validation in that.

In your plugins `init`:

```
    craft()->on('commerce_addresses.onBeforeSaveAddress',
        [
            craft()->businessLogic_logic,
            'onBeforeSaveAddressHandler'
        ]
    );
```

And then the actual handler in my case this is in my `BusinessLogic_LogicService`:

```
public function onBeforeSaveAddressHandler($event){

    $address = $event->params['address'];

    if(!$address->firstName){
        $address->addError('firstName','First name must not be empty');
        $event->performAction = false;
    }
    ...etc, anything else you want really
}
```

...that's the essence of it really.  You can do any validation you like, and just add errors as you need them and set `$event->performAction = false;` to stop the dodgy address being saved.

....and looks like Luke is creating something easier for V2, but this is at least effective and works for now!